# converting a FOR loop to a DO WHILE loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, do-while

im trying to convert this into a do-while; it is supposed to show a pyramid based on a number that you have entered:

```
    int size,a,b,c;
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("\n");

    // for loop starts here
    for(a=1; a<=size; a++)
    {

     for(b=1; b<=size-a; b++)
     {
      printf(" ");
     }

     for(c=1; c<=(2*a)-1; c++)
     {
      printf("*");
     }

      printf("\n");
    }
     getch();
   }
```

this is what i have done so far:

```
    int size;
    int a=1;
    int b=1;
    int c=1;

    do {

     a++;

      do {
       c++;
       printf("*");
      } while(c<=((2*a)-1));

        do {
       printf(" ");
          b++;
      } while(b<=(size-a));

      printf("\n");

    } while(a<=size);

    getch();
   }
```

Aaaaand its not showing the same output, any suggestion guys? TIA :)

Comment: Is this really C++ ? Looks like pure C to me (without the usual nice formatting)

Comment: Have you properly initialized `a`, `b` and `c` in your second code segment?

Comment: Where are the initial values of `a`, `b` and `c`???

Comment: It would very nice if you post the output of both pieces of code.

Answer (score 11):

A for loop

```
for (BEGIN; COND; INC)
{
    WORK;
}
```

Is equivalent to the while loop

```
{
    BEGIN;
    while (COND)
    {
        WORK;
        INC;
    }
}
```

… except for the effect of a `continue` statement in the `WORK` part (with a `for` loop the `continue` jumps to the `INC`), and except that names declared in the `for` loop’s `BEGIN` are in the same declarative region as those declared in
the `COND`.

It doesn't make an elegant do-while loop, however.

```
{
    BEGIN;
    do
    {
        if (! COND) break;
        WORK;
        INC;
    } while (true)
}
```

Alternatively (although it repeats code)

```
{
    BEGIN;
    if (COND)
    {
        do
        {
            WORK;
            INC;
        } while (COND)
    }
}
```

Comment: but we were told to only use "Do while" statement, but is it possible without using "if"? thanks :)

Comment: No, obviously not because a `for` loop might have zero iterations (e.g. if `size == 0`) while `do {} while` has at least one. You need to somehow handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers actually tend to convert for-loops to the code equivalent of do-while loops. The result looks like this (using Neil Kirk's metavariables):

```
BEGIN;
if(COND) {
    do {
        WORK;
        INC;
    } while(COND);
}
```

Note that `COND` appears in two different places. If you examine the generated assembly for a for-loop, you'll usually see that effect, unless the optimizer is clever enough to figure out (or told by the programmer using `__assume`) that `COND` will never be false the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int size;
    int i=1;
    int j;
    int k;
    printf("Enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    do
    {
        j=i;
        do
        {
            printf(" ");  
            j++;
        }while(j<=size);
        k=1;
        do
        {
            printf("*");
            k++;
        }while(k<=(2*i)-1);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }while(i<=size);
}
```

Comment: This is what you wanted,isn't it?